ECDSA signature getting truncated
I am trying to create an ECDSA signature and it's getting created perfectly most of the time but sometimes it's getting truncated randomly like the r and s value are both supposed to be 48 but sometimes I am getting 47 for one and 48 for other. I can't tell what the issue is, is it an issue with the signature or is there an issue with the procedure used for obtaining the r and s value from the signature?
    const BIGNUM *r;
    const BIGNUM *s;
    ECDSA_SIG_get0(signature, &r, &s);
    char *R = BN_bn2hex(r);
    char *S = BN_bn2hex(s);
    int r_len = BN_num_bytes(r);
    int s_len = BN_num_bytes(s);
    uint8_t *r_bytes = (uint8_t *)malloc(r_len);
    uint8_t *s_bytes = (uint8_t *)malloc(s_len);
    BN_bn2bin(r, r_bytes);
    BN_bn2bin(s, s_bytes);
    int signature_len = r_len + s_len;
    uint8_t *signature2 = (uint8_t *)malloc(signature_len);
    memcpy(signature2, r_bytes, r_len);
    memcpy(signature2 + r_len, s_bytes, s_len);
    int max_encoded_len = EVP_ENCODE_LENGTH(signature_len);
    *ppcSignature1 = (char *)calloc(max_encoded_len,1);

I have tried to get the r and s value again from the same signature by adding this code block :
if(r_len != 48 || s_len != 48){
    const BIGNUM *r_temp = ECDSA_SIG_get0_r(signature);
    const BIGNUM *s_temp = ECDSA_SIG_get0_s(signature);
    char *R_temp = BN_bn2hex(r_temp);
    char *S_temp = BN_bn2hex(s_temp);
    printf("R_LEN : %s\n",R_temp);
    printf("S_LEN : %s\n",S_temp);
}

And still the values of the rlen and slen was the same.

How often does it seem to be truncated? Could it be 1 out of 256 times? You're not counting the "size" of the signature, BN_num_bytes gives the number of significant bytes. If the most-significant byte happens to be 0, what would you expect?

@ThomasJager I think it is close to 1 out of 256 times.

There does not appear to be an issue with truncation of the signature, but rather with the interpretation of the value returned by BN_num_bytes (noting that it's a function-like macro.)
BN_num_bytes indicates how many bytes would be needed for an integer value to hold the number in a BIGNUM. This does not mean that the signature consists of fewer bytes, it's still a 48-byte value. But if BN_num_bytes returns 47, then you know that, interpreting that number as having 48 bytes, the upper 8-15 bits of the value will be 0.
If you happened to have a signature with the value 0x34529, then you would obtain the value 3 from BN_num_bytes, as you only need three bytes to represent that number. In other words it has 3 significant bytes.

From the notes on the page describing BN_num_bytes:

Some have tried using BN_num_bits() on individual numbers in RSA keys, DH keys and DSA keys, and found that they don't always come up with the number of bits they expected (something like 512, 1024, 2048, ...). This is because generating a number with some specific number of bits doesn't always set the highest bits, thereby making the number of significant bits a little lower. If you want to know the "key size" of such a key, either use functions like RSA_size(), DH_size() and DSA_size(), or use BN_num_bytes() and multiply with 8 (although there's no real guarantee that will match the "key size", just a lot more probability).

The documentation notes the issue with using BN_num_bits to get a key size in bits, which has 50/50 odds of actually matching the expected key size. It then notes that you can use BN_num_bytes, but it's only more likely to give you the correct result, not guaranteed (from 1/2 to 1/256 chance of a wrong result.)

BN_num_bytes can be useful for allocation space, but it's not going to give you information on the nature of the signature. It's a generic tool related to BIGNUM, it doesn't "know" how big you signature is, it just sees a number.

Thanks for your help! I wanted to get the BIGNUM values r and s of the ecdsa signature within the ECDSA_SIG structure how do I do that then? Is there an alternative way ?

@AjithNair Isn't that what you're already doing? I focused on the BN_num_bytes issue, but it seems like you're getting the signatures correctly in the first code block. If the issue is that the different sizes break the encoding you do after, then I'd suggest instead allocating your new signature2 for the signatures being 48 bytes (ignoring the values you get from BN_num_bytes, instead signature_len = 48 + 48), then copying to something like signature2 + (48 - r_len) and signature2 + r_len + (48 - s_len) (or some cleaner variant).

(Also making sure to zero those bytes that aren't being filled by the signatures.)

@AjithNair What do you mean by truncated? Were there close to 96 characters? You also don't use the values returned by BN_bn2hex, they're only shown to be used in the second code block.

Yeah you are right, Thanks for the help
